# There is no message icon in bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use Bootstrap v3.1.1 (http://getbootstrap.com) and I want to use icon-message-* from the icons that is listed [here](http://marcoceppi.github.io/bootstrap-glyphicons/) , but there is no such classes in bootstrap. how should I use them?

I addedd this lines to head part:

```
  <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

and this is the code that I want to use... but there is no css class for "icon-message-new"

```
   <span class="glyphicon icon-message-new"></span>
```

Comment: Show your code. It could be that you have not included the required files.

Comment: The glyphicons that are provided by bootstrap are linked here: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons. The other ones come out of a different stylesheet.. Yours is not listed in the glyphicons from Bootstrap, thus you need a different css. Also might not have put the font where glyphicons are put in your css.

Comment: The icon that you want to use from the library you linked to in your question is not a font-icon (as noted in your comment to @dorvalla).  If you want to use a font-icon, find a different icon font or if can't find exactly the style icon you want, you can use http://icomoon.io/app or fontello.com to create your own font-icons from SVG files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hers is the message icon in Bootstrap:

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i>
```

I will recommend to use Fontawesome 
http://fontawesome.io/icons/ 
rather than Bootstraps's Glyph-icon . Font awesome has 479 icons free to use.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap doesn't provide the full glyphicons. It has included just 200, and the one you refer to is not listed at the ones bootstrap supports (see the http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons link fo those details)

To get the complete glyphicons you want, grab them from Github. It's even listen on the page you linked us too.

https://github.com/marcoceppi/bootstrap-glyphicons

Comment: your link uses a picture as icon, and I can't change the color of them and of course the quality is not like a font icon...